# How to use shell variable for headers of curl command

Tags: shell, curl

I am trying to store multiple headers in 1 $HEADER shell variable and use it with CURL.

```
HEADERS="-H \"X-API-KEY: $API_KEY\" -H \"Content-Type: application/json\""
URL="https://myendpoint"

curl -v $HEADERS -X GET  $URL
```

I tried different combination like using "$HEADERS" instead of $HEADERS
but it didn't work

Comment: BTW, this general issue is the subject of [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, so that the parameters are recognized as separate entries:

```
HEADERS=(-H "X-API-KEY: $API_KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json")
URL="https://myendpoint"

curl -v "${HEADERS[@]}" -X GET "$URL"
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you very much

Comment: @wrlee, for future note -- in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the bullet point regarding questions which *...have already been asked and answered many times before* under the heading "Answer Well-Asked Questions".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It isn't always obvious to me when a question has already been been asked/answered. I assume  they'd posed the question because they didn't find the answer, so I am willing to answer within the context in which they asked.

Comment: Understood. This one in particular is rather a FAQ, though -- you're likely to see it again (and again, and again...) if you hang around for long. (Indeed, it's a FAQ [in more places than here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).